# Plink-How can I create .map file for Plink?

Tags: plink, genetics

I was trying to analyze allele frequency differences between groups by PLINK. Due to `PLINK` requires PED and MAP files, I was trying to prepare both.

However, I have some questions.

Regarding the MAP file: 
I only identified 17 SNPs for my study. These are part of my data:

```
0 rs10119 0 44903416
0 rs111514285 0 44890428
0 rs1160983 0 44893972
... ...
```

The 4th list is physical positions that I found in NCBI. And I saved the file as .txt, then I changed the file extension to .map(I was not sure if it was correct).

When I ran the command `" --file mydata"` in PLINK.There was an "Error: Failed to open Mydata.map."

How can I create correct MAP file?

## These are my plink.log

```
PLINK v1.90p 64-bit (30 Nov 2019)
Options in effect:
  --file ADdata # my data file'name is ADdata
  --out Mydata # the output log file is called "Mydata"

Hostname: gongjingwendeMacBook-Pro.local
Working directory: /Users/gongjingwen/plink_mac
Start time: Thu Dec  5 13:42:36 2019

Random number seed: 1575524556
8192 MB RAM detected; reserving 4096 MB for main workspace.
Error: Failed to open ADdata.map.

End time: Thu Dec  5 13:42:36 2019
```

I hope you can help me soon! Have a nice day!

Kind regards.
Jingwen

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the filenames used as input and the complete log output from plink.

Comment: Vince, thanks for your reply! I added the log file and I thought maybe my PED file was fine. It concludes FID IID PID MID SEX PHENO and SNPs information.

Comment: Are you certain `ADdata.map` exists along with `ADdata.ped`? The error would indicate that the file does not exist.

Comment: Yes, it does exist along with ADdata.ped. And my MAP file is manual edited by myself(I followed the content and format of the file downloaded from the website and filled it in manually). Or would you tell me how to generate MAP file? eg. by programming software? R? or something else? It is rarely mentioned on the Internet so I can't find it...

Comment: `.map` format is here https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/formats#map. Maybe chromosome designation is invalid as you have it set to `0`. Also, if you want more help please post extract of first few lines from each file.